# Extendable factory design pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, factory-pattern

Following are my import factory classes. If I want to add new ImportTypes then just add new type in ImportTypes enums and add a case in factory class and it works fine.

My question is how can I make it more independent and easy to extend. Lets say a user wants to add a new ImportType then instead of changing code, he writes his own DLL and implements interface... any good suggestions/ideas?

**Import types**

```
enum ImportTypes
{
   DefaultImport,
   C2CImport
}
```

**Import interface**

```
public interface IImportService
{
   void Import(Argument arguments, ImportDefinition config);
}
```

**Import factory**

```
class ImportFactory
    {
    public static IImportService GetService(ImportTypes type)
    {
       switch (type)
       {
           case ImportTypes.DefaultImport:
               return new DefaultImportService();

           case ImportTypes.C2CImport:
               return new C2CImportService();
       }

       return null;
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
IImportService docImportService = ImportFactory.GetService(ImportTypes.DefaultImport);
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, you need to support registering new services at runtime. As such, you can't use an `enum`, as the services aren't known in advance; they'll need to be referenced via eg strings:

```
class ImportServiceHandler
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Type> _importServices =
        new Dictionary<string, Type>();

    public ImportServiceHandler()
    {
        RegisterService("DefaultImport", typeof(DefaultImportService));
        RegisterService("C2CImport", typeof(C2CImportService));
    }

    public void RegisterService(string name, Type serviceType)
    {
        if (!serviceType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IImportService)))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Type specified doesn't implement IImportService", nameof(serviceType));
        }
        _importServices.Add(name, serviceType);
    }

    public IImportService GetService(string name)
    {
        if (_importServices.ContainsKey(name))
        {
            return (IImportService)Activator.CreateInstance(_importServices[name]);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way...

In your switch statement, a "default" would handle any unrecognized types.  The type would be looked up in your program's configuration.  A user would have to add their type and a path to the assembly that implements the type.  They would need to implement your interface.  The default case would then load the assembly and instantiate the object and return that to you.

You would use AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load() to load an assembly.
You would use {Assembly}.CreateInstance() to instantiate your object.

```
class ImportFactory
{
  public static IImportService GetService(ImportTypes type)
  {
     switch (type)
     {
         case ImportTypes.DefaultImport:
             return new DefaultImportService();
         case ImportTypes.C2CImport:
             return new C2CImportService();
         default:
             return CustomImportService(type);
     } 
     return null;
  }
}
```

The CustomImportService would look something like this...

```
IImportService CustomImportService(ImportTypes type)
{
    var assmBytes = GetAssemblyIDByType(type);  // you would implement this based on your configuration approach
    var assm = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(assmBytes);
    var obj = (IImportService)assm.CreateInstance("IImportService");
    return obj;
}
```

This is just a start of course and needs work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the prototype pattern.

Create a class that receives the Import types at runtime, and return clones of these objects.

It will allow you to load ImportTypes at runtime and the factory class doesn't need to be changed.

http://www.dofactory.com/net/prototype-design-pattern

This link shows the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like this:
(error handling omitted for clarity)

```
public class Factory {

    //store how different objects are created
    private IDictionary<string, Func<IImportService>> mappings = new Dictionary<string, Func<IImportService>>()

    public void Register(string key, Func<IImportService> expression) 
    {
         mappings[key] = expression;
    }

    public IImportService GetService(string key)
    {
         return mappings[key]();
    }
}
```

this can be used in the following way then:

```
factory.Register("service", () => new MyCustomImportService());
```

If you know the type you want at compile time you could provide overrides that take the type in the signature. i.e. `Register<MyCustomImportService>(...)` and `GetService<MyCustomImportService>`. At this point it would probably would be useful to consider if you want some lightweight IoC container

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious to know how you can make an extendable factory pattern when you're using an enum to decide which implementation to return. This means that everytime someone builds a new DLL with new implementation logic, you will have to refactor the original code (maybe this is a harsh description, since all you're doing is adding a new enum element), and rebuild it too. It kind of defeats the purpose.

I'd strongly suggest not doing it this way. In fact, I can't see how a factory pattern can be considered a good fit for what you are desiring to do, which is more along the lines of a pluggable framework that only knows that it has to return an `IImportService` implementation as requested by the calling code.

This kind of application design really calls for a dependency injection based approach. Something like `MEF`, maybe? You might be able to get away by defining the dependencies like this:

```
[Export("C2CImport", typeof(IImportService))]
public class C2CImportService : IImportService
```

In addition to `[Import]`-ing the dependency into the code you want, you can manually resolve the dependency like this:

```
myCompositionContainer.GetExports<IImportService>("C2CImport");
```

(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833299(v=vs.110).aspx)